# How do I ensure user login is correct for ef core generated database?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, integration-testing, .net-6.0

I am currently using EF Core code first to implement my database. For my integration tests I am creating a new instance each time they're run. The creation is done using the command:

```
_context.Database.EnsureCreated()
```

But when I try to use the database I get the user issue below.

> Cannot open database "ApollosLibraryIDP_2022-03-18_T18-47-08-5553551+11:00" requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user 'WADEPERSONALLAP\wados'.

Does anyone have any ideas or pointers?

I already tried to use `_context.Database.Migrate()` but it had the same result.

Comment: Have you checked the SQL Server instance's ERRORLOG yet? Find the 18456 error messages, take note of the State number displayed there, and compare it against [MSSQLSERVER_18456](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/mssqlserver-18456-database-engine-error) to determine what the problem is.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning getting 'Could not find database requested by user.' which is odd as I can see it in SSMS.

Comment: Is your SQL Server instance configured to use CS (case-sensitive) collations on the system databases? Perhaps the database name in your connection string doesn't exactly match the lettercase of the database name itself?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning
I dynamically generate the name on the fly and should be used throughout the app. Let me make sure the connection string is correct throughout the app.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Found it, thanks for the help. Pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

What was happening is that the way I creating the definition for injecting the database in my test fixture. I was creating a new db name in the connection string every time the DB was injected.

So to fix this my code went from:

```
services.AddDbContext<ApollosLibraryIDPContext>(opt =>
{
    var connectionString = localConfig.GetSection("ConnectionString").Value;
    opt.UseSqlServer(connectionString.Replace("{UniqueId}", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm_ss"));
});
```

And changed to:

```
var connectionString = localConfig.GetSection("ConnectionString").Value;
var conn = connectionString.Replace("{UniqueId}", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm_ss"));

services.AddDbContext<ApollosLibraryIDPContext>(opt =>
{
    opt.UseSqlServer(conn);
});
```